# How to implement Push Notifications in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I have followed all the steps of above link. Now my push notification Apple id, certificates and settings have been done.

Can anyone suggest what would be the next steps.

Comment: You need a service to send the notifications from.  Check out Parse.

Comment: service we have to hit from our app or somewhere else. Can you share any demo this type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call that service from application side.

```
- (void)callService
  {
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/test/samplePush.php"]];

      NSMutableURLRequest * rq  = [ NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 

      [rq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

      [rq setValue:postLen forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];    

      [rq setValue:@"application/x-www-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

       NSURLConnection *con  = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:rq delegate:self];

      NSLog(@"%@",postLen);
     if(con) {
      NSLog(@"connected");
       }
   NSLog(@"%@",con);
}
```

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client  I am working on this line

Comment: because the client is sending the message from the GCM and android person also doing that in their app. If you have an idea pls share, I don't have idea about it.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client  I done the steps 1 to 4 can you confirm further how to proceed.

Comment: I have received the message connected to GCM and received token  can you confirm what is to filled in this strings //    _registrationKey = @"onRegistrationCompleted";
 _messageKey = @"onMessageReceived";

Comment: after running this command in terminal   getting error can you suggest             openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert.pem -key certkey.pem
Enter pass phrase for certkey.pem:
unable to load certificate
858:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.40.1/src/crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:648:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Comment: HI Ekta I have implemented the Push notificatiion and now message is received successfully in my devices. Now I am receiving the JSON and this JSOn printing in the notification alert how this can be changed and we can show the view page once clicked there.

Answer (score 0):

In his tutorial, the guy explain very well how to send a push notification, using a php script. 
You can easily use it if you have MAMP installed in your Mac. You can also use a free service as [PushWoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/) to send push notification.